# lookup of one-to-many relationship matching to objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a meetup clone for practice with mongodb. I am interested in the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) stage of the mongodb aggregation. I have a denormalized document that looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  createdAt: ISODate(),
  description: "Group for people who like kittens",
  members: [ ObjectId(), ObjectId() ]
}
```

My aim is to look up the `members` from the collection `users` and join them simply like so:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  createdAt: ISODate(),
  description: "Group for people who like kittens.",
  members: [{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: "Jeff"
  }, {
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: "Tim"
  }]
}
```

When I try to do `$lookup` on the array, it yields no results, so I do `$unwind` which gives me several documents that I have to group.

```
db.meetups.aggregate([
  { $match: { "_id": id } },
  { $unwind: "$users" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "members",
      localField: "users",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "members"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      members: { $push: "$members" }
    }
  }
], /** ... */);
```

The problem is that this always yields an array with a single element, because I only ever expect one element. I've tried using the `$group` operator, but then it is just an array filled with single element arrays rather than a series of objects

How is this done with mongo 3.2?

Comment: Add the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to the pipeline?

Comment: added it now, last part

Comment: You are  pushing whole array, which results with 2D array. Either unwind `members` after `$lookup` and before `$group` or `$push` only first element of the array.